# jquery tree selection

Tags: jquery

I have cats with tree hierarchy, for example, country->city. So that you should first choose country, and then city. 
Or big catalog for products. You should choose several "folders", to get for specific product.

Yahoo's answers have this:
[image]

And some business catalogs sites with big products lists.

I have all cats in php and can pass them to javascript.
How can I Implement it on one page? Is there any jquery plugin for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We call this problem as cascading dropdowns problem. You can search on google as

cascading dropdowns using jQuery
cascasding dropdowns Ajax

to get several examples.