# Can anyone suggest nice Jquery Decision maker plug-in or demo

Tags: jquery-plugins

Can anyone suggest nice Jquery Decision maker plug-in or demo, I have the one below, but its not that good http://listui.com/?p=84

Answer (score 1):

My Google-fu brings up [jQuery Option Tree](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-option-tree/) and [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699151/jquery-tree-selection) which leads to the more common name of "cascading dropdowns" or "cascading selects", for which there are [a few plugins in the jQuery plugin directory](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/cascading) and I'm sure more via Google